# Set axis values range for surf function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm plotting a surface in matlab, where the x and y values are 0.15-0.85, with 0.05 gaps (0.15,0.2,0.25...).

However, when I plot the surface, the axis are on a 0.0 - 1.0 range, with 0.1 jumps (0.0, 0.1, 0.2...) so the entire surface is distorted. How do I set the axis ranges and deltas?

Comment: I am not sure about the deltas, but you can scale the figure with `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])`.

Comment: and at the end of the documentation of "axes" you find `XTick`, `XTickLabel` and `XTickMode` guess with `set`-function and those commands you should be able to change the ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as written in my comments you could solve your problem like this:

```
figure(1)
surf(data)
axis([0.15 0.85 0.15 0.85])
set(gca, 'XTick',0.20:0.05:0.80)
set(gca, 'YTick',0.20:0.05:0.80)
```